# Parse variables to HTML file in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny App, where I want a part of the output to be data sheet based on input. In order to make it look nice, my idea is to generate it based on some HTML code. However I’m not very familiar with HTML, but I would need to parse values from input and values calculated in the R code ( “varA”, “varB” and “varC”) to the HTML code. Any suggestions on how to do that smart?

I’ve attached an example showing my idea

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("MyTable"),
   
   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),
      
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("filetable")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
   
   Reactive_Var<-reactive({
     
     #Variables I vould like to parse to HTML
     varA <- input$bins
     varB <- varA^2
     varC <- varB^2
     
     pbhtml <- paste(
       readLines(paste(getwd(),'/mytable.html',sep=""))
     )
     HTML(pbhtml)
   })
   
   output$filetable <- renderUI({Reactive_Var()})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**mytable.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title></title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Calibri"; font-size:x-small }
        a.comment-indicator:hover + comment { background:#ffd; position:absolute; display:block; border:1px solid black; padding:0.5em;  } 
        a.comment-indicator { background:red; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; width:0.5em; height:0.5em;  } 
        comment { display:none;  } 
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <colgroup width="175"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="3" width="64"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="103"></colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" height="20" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#A9D18E"><b><font color="#000000">My Table</font></b></td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#A9D18E"><b><font color="#000000"><br></font></b></td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#A9D18E"><b><font color="#000000">Value</font></b></td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#A9D18E"><b><font color="#000000"><br></font></b></td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#A9D18E"><b><font color="#000000">Value Squared</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="20" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="20" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><b><font color="#000000">Numbers of bins</font></b></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="right" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4" sdval="2" sdnum="1033;"><font color="#000000">varA</font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="right" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4" sdval="4" sdnum="1033;"><font color="#000000">varB</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="20" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><b><font color="#000000"><br></font></b></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="20" align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><b><font color="#000000">Numbers of bins squared</font></b></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="right" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4" sdval="4" sdnum="1033;"><font color="#000000">varB</font></td>
        <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="right" valign=bottom bgcolor="#C5E0B4" sdval="16" sdnum="1033;"><font color="#000000">varC</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- ************************************************************************** -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to check if I understand. You have a template HTML and you want to put some values in that template, and then include the result in your app?

Comment: yes myTable.html is a template for the table which is a part of the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following.

1. Take the following css code

```css
        body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Calibri"; font-size:x-small }
        a.comment-indicator:hover + comment { background:#ffd; position:absolute; display:block; border:1px solid black; padding:0.5em;  }
        a.comment-indicator { background:red; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; width:0.5em; height:0.5em;  }
        comment { display:none;  }
```

and put it in a separate file. Then load it via one of the methods explained [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

2. Create a template function in R.

This function takes as arguments the values that you want to replace in your template HTML, inserts them in the correct places, and returns the filled template string. The following is a minimal example (yours is going to be bigger)

```r
my_template <- function(name, lastname, age) {
  glue::glue(
    "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{name}</td>
    <td>{lastname}</td>
    <td>{age}</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
  )
}

my_template("Michael", "Jordan", "50")
```

Make sure you only take the code between  and  tags and not everything included in your HTML file.

4. Pass the result of the call to that function to `renderUI()` (make sure it is reactive) and then keep the `htmlOutput()` as is.

Please let me know if this doesn't work or if you need extra clarification :)

Comment: Thanks - just the input I needed

Comment: Cool! Could you accept the answer if it helped? Thank you